# "I'm flabbergasted!" - Old fashioned? Pedantic? Refined? Educated?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

> To flabbergast - to overwhelm with shock, surprise, or wonder.

"I'm flabbergasted!" - I have only one friend who uses this phrase, so I can't figure out what kind of person uses it.  Although NGram shows it to be on the rise, I never hear it from my acquaintances. Is it old-fashioned but coming back into usage? Pedantic? Refined? Educated? Gender-specific vocabulary?
[image: Questionable NGrams chart from books.google.com purporting to show growth in usage of the word flabbergasted since the early 1900s]

Comment: A tad old-fashioned, perhaps. Not pedantic or refined. If it's "educated" then I am flabbergasted by the state of educational systems. All in all, a fine word.

Comment: "A tad.....", a good addition to my vocabulary.

Comment: @Robusto What do you say about the NGram ?

Comment: What @Robusto said. [My flabber has never been so gasted](http://www.kgbanswers.co.uk/whos-catch-phrase-was-my-flabber-has-never-been-so-gasted/3253589) either. ***Women's** language???* What's *that* supposed to mean?

Comment: @Luis: Here's [what I say about NGrams in general](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2469/2303). What I say about this one in particular is that you should take a close look at the magnitude of the numbers on the Y axis and see what conclusions you draw.

Comment: Women's Language?! What the hell is that then... I wasn't aware we women had a separate 'language', my words are the same as men's, whatever the subject? But I'm intrigued and would like an explanation, or alternatively, my gast is so flabbered that it requires an explanation...UNLESS, hmm, do you mean gynaecological expressions - if so, absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: I was curious, so I had to Google. It turns out, in some cultures, there actually is a [separate language for women](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_and_gender#Gender-specific_vocabulary)! And even in English, studies since the 70s have demonstrated women use it differently (both in terms of word-choice and grammar).

Comment: Japanese men and women use different verb forms, pronouns, etc. Men tend to speak a "rougher" version of the language, although—as with everything in Japanese—much depends on one's relative status with respect to the interlocutor.

Comment: @bamboo I apologize if I sounded offensive. The truth is that in any language, there are words which are used more often by men and words which are undoubtedly used more often by women. The latter would include all the vocabulary about make-up and fashion. That's true anywhere; in the US, in England, in Japan or in Chile.  No matter whether civilized or not, chauvinist or not, there is always some difference in vocabulary between boys and girls, men and women.

Comment: @Robusto  Fortunately I had statistics at Medical School and I have no difficulty to understand graphs. NGrams must have been criticized by statisticians but it is practical and gives us an idea about how much a word or phrase has been used throughout the years. The number of times "I'm flabbergasted" appears is insignificant, I know.  Despite that, what I meant to ask you is whether you agree with an ascending curve for the bigram during the last three decades.

Comment: @Luis: I'm neither a professional statistician nor a linguistics expert. But what I suspect that trend line shows is not that the term is used more, but that it is seen in print more. That could be the natural outcome of what once may have been a slangy term becoming more accepted, and books getting less fussy about using slang terms. But I wouldn't want to fall on my sword in support of this conjecture. The term is attested from 1772, and so one would expect its usage to grow if English found it useful, which apparently—and unsurprisingly—it does.

Comment: @Luis Oh I see what you mean, thanks for the explanation, just sounds weird 'women's language'. In the UK, there was a comedian called Frankie Howerd who used the term 'my gast is flabbered' as part of his routine, a sort of catch phrase. Everyone knew it meant flabbergasted, don't hear people say it much any more, so I'd say it's just old fashioned, but still familiar to most.

Comment: Unlike @Robusto I AM a statistician (though not a linguistics sort) and advise caution in using ngrams unless fully cognizant of all assumptions, boundary values etc. Robusto is closest to being correct around here (excluding the linguistics PhDs who are always correct), I've found. Here's a possibility for flabbergasted: books that used it have been emerging from their  70 to 90 years of copyright, NOT that the word is more popular.

Comment: Continued, as the basis for my conjecture, see how the [entire 19th century sprang back into print](http://sappingattention.blogspot.com/2014/04/biblio-bizarre-who-publishes-in-google.html) due to out-of-copyright publisher BiblioBazaar's arrival. It provides almost 45% of the 2008 sample in Google Ngrams. This isn't necessarily the explanation for flabbergasted's resurgence but it must be ruled out as a cause if using the Google ngram viewer.

Comment: @FeralOink  Thank you. I understand and I'm always very careful about data interpretation.  I'm an M.D. and I had statistics at Med School, which gave me not more than a basic knowledge to recognize reliable data.  When I need a protocol for a study, however, I always have to look for a statistician's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to your questions are:

- No (not particularly old-fashioned)
- No (not particularly pedantic)
- No (not particularly "*refined*")
- No (not particularly "*educated*")

What makes you suppose that it is any of those things?

Just because "*[you] never hear it from [your] acquaintances*" does not mean that others do not use it.

[Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discombobulated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscombobulated%3B%2Cc0) is a similar ngram for *discombobulated*, for your enjoyment.

Comment: "Just because "[you] never hear it from [your] acquaintances" does not mean that others do not use it."  Good to know that. I was wondering whether my never hearing it might be due to the word being restricted to a special group: the aged, intellectuals. The person I sometimes hear it from, is a 71 year-old Canadian. So I thought it might be old-fashioned. I'm a non-native speaker who wants to know more. My questions may sound stupid but my intention is to learn.

Comment: FWIW, your questions do not sound stupid to me. This question is not stupid. I did wonder what made you suppose this (*What kind of person...?*). I guess it was based on your Canadian acquaintance and not hearing the term otherwise. It is **good** to pose the question to find out - far better than just going with a foregone conclusion based a tiny sample. I applaud you for that. And now you know. ;-)

Comment: FWIW ???  For whoever is wondering?  For what it's Worth?   Forgot where I was?

Comment: Sorry. [Lmgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=fwiw).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Drew that it is "none of the above".

I would surmise that your friend is probably well-read, and perhaps even a bit animated, in general. Readers are exposed to a much wider variety of vocabulary, and it's always good to get more words out there in circulation. Glad to hear they were flabbergasted.

As an aside: My wife is a librarian...She's got some exceptional words.